# connecting to IRC and log all conversations

Tags: irc, logger

I would like to setup a tool on my server that automatically connects to a certain irc channel and logs all conversations.

Also this tool should

- welcome a certain user with a certain pre-defined message
- and inform me via email, that the user logged in.

What kind of tools/scripts will do such things?

Answer (score 0):

What you're most likely looking for is a bot. [Here's a good example](http://classam.github.io/pierc/), and it should do everything you need.